# How to check if an array has enough empty/null "consecutive" positions to place values together randomly in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, if-statement, random

I'm creating a commercial airline flight program and I'm still learning how to get around with Java. So, I was wondering if there was any way to check if an array has enough consecutive positions to place values together in those positions in the array?
For example, I have an array of strings called seats, each position in this array corresponds to an available seat on the flight. Initially these seats are all empty.

```
String[] seats = new String[8];
```

In the long-run, this program is going to be inserting values into this array and I want my program to be able to check if there are any empty seats(positions) in the flight(array) to assign a passenger to a seat. I sketched this to check.

```
for(int i=0; i< seats.length-1;i++) {
if(seats[i] != null) {
     do something;
   } else {
       system.out.println("No seats available");
       (how do I not assign seats or accept more values to my array?)
   }
}
```

but advised on using an objective approach, I got to this

```
private static int MAX_SEATS = 8;
private String[] seats = new String[MAX_SEATS];

public boolean addPassenger(String passengerName) {
    for (int i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
        if (seats[i] == null) {
            seats[i] = passengerName;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If the program finds an empty seat after checking, It should then check again if there are empty consecutive seats. (For example, if we wanted to make 3 passengers seat together, the program should check if there are empty 3 seats and then seat them there). If the program finds 3 consecutive positions in the array, it should randomly assign the passengers to whichever 3 position. otherwise it should randomly try another seat, repeating until successful.
Right now, my array of seat can take up to 8 values, so the possible 3 positions could be `(1,2,3 or 2,3,4 or 3,4,5 or 4,5,6 or 5,6,7)`. If the program does not find a consecutive position to seat these 3 people, it should randomly place them in different positions.(pick random seat numbers till it can find an empty seat)
*This code is just adding passengers to the seats array .*

```
//accepting more values to the seats array
public boolean addPassengers(String... passengerNames) {
    boolean everyoneAdded = true;
    for (String passengerName : passengerNames) {
        everyoneAdded = everyoneAdded && addPassenger(passengerName);
    }
    return everyoneAdded;
}
```

How is it possible to check for **consecutive positions** in an array in order to add groups of passengers randomly? Any correction/contribution would be helpful.

Comment: Either you need to create a class which managers the array and tracks the used/unused positions, or you need to loop over the array and count the number of consecutive `null` elements (or use a `ArrayList`)

Comment: And using an indexed loop is one way you might look-ahead (or behind).

Comment: "How is it possible to check for **stuff** anywhere in an array?" -> `for(int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {if(checkForStuff(array, k)) return true;} return false;`

Comment: @immibis no, thats not the question. Theres a difference between checking for stuff anywhere in the array and checking for stuff consecutively in the array. Your code is checking for one position in the array and not consecutively.

Comment: @girlCoder "Stuff" could be "3 consecutive nulls starting at this position".